# How to enter time as 00:00:00 in MUI X DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker, mui-x

- React:18.2.0
- mui/material: 5.10.5
- date-fns: 2.29.3
- date-io/date-fns: 2.16.0
- formik: 2.2.9

I want to use DateTimePicker in my project. i want enter time this format: Hour:Minute:second
but  Currently, I can only enter 00:00 Hour:Minute.
how can fix it ?
Also, I checked the mui documentation, but I didn't find an answer.
[image]

I tried

```
<DateTimePicker
  mask="____/__/__ __:__:__"
  format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
  ampm={false}
    openTo="year"
     views={[
     'year',
     'month',
     'day',
     'hours',
      'minutes',
     'seconds'
          ]}
/>
```

but didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `inputFormat="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`